# I often get confused by the usage of "located " and "situated"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Situated vs Located?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/situated-vs-located)

Can I have a few examples to comprehend?